# How did Yuyutsu die?

Tags: mahabharata

Yuyutsu switched from the side of Kauravas to the Pandavas and survived the 18-day war. Many years after Mahabharata war when Krishna passes away, Pandavas decide to renounce the world. Abhimanyu's son Parikshit is coronated as the king of Hastinapura.

https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m17/m17001.htm

> Resolved to retire from the world for earning merit, they brought Yuyutsu before them. **Yudhishthira made over the kingdom to the son of his uncle by his Vaisya wife. Installing Parikshit also on their throne**, as king, the eldest brother of the Pandavas, filled with sorrow, addressed Subhadra, saying, ‘This son of thy son will be the king of the Kurus.**

My question is, how did Yuyutsu die?

Comment: "the son of his uncle by his Vaisya wife" -- this means Yuyutsu only..so Yuyutsu was given responsibility of guide to the king.. this is self answer Q...

Comment: No, I meant what happened after the coronation like how did yuyutsu die?